# てんで方向ちがいじゃない！ DB Chapter2 Double negatives

Tags: translation, negation

Translated as: "It's completely in the wrong direction!"

> てんで = Completely / At all
>
> 方向【ほうこう】 = direction
>
> ちがい = wrong
>
> じゃない = is not

I'm struggling with doble negatives in japanese. In my mind I'd translate this as: "Is not the wrong direction at all!".

For the intended meaning, I wonder why is not correct to just say: てんで方向ちがいだ！

I'd understand that meaning if the ending was a question, as in: てんで方向ちがいじゃないの？ , but this was not the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/505/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1485/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11918/9831

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, what is this 'DB' you reference in many of your questions?

Comment: ^ それはたぶん「ドラゴンボール」かな

Comment: DB = Dragon Ball. Sorry this time I didn't clarify.

Comment: Ok, so basically じゃない ending will almost always be the tag question, even if not followed by の or か or ？. In the only case of な adjectives there's ambiguity, usually solved by intonation or one of the 3 mentioned characters.